# Parse XML into Java Object List using simpleframework

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

I have an xml like shown. I want to convert this document into equivalent Java object shown below

```
<page>
   <body>
    <category id="category-0_2">
        <container title="Spotlight" slug="spotlight"></container>
        <container title="Just Added Shows" slug="just_added_shows"></container>
        <container title="Originals" slug="originals"></container>
        <container title="Popular TV Shows" slug="popular_tv_shows"></container>
        <container title="Wonder Women" slug="wonder_women"></container>
    </category>
  </body>
</page>



public class HomeXML {
    Page page;
    Body body;
    Category category;
    List<Container> containerList;
}
```

Is it possible to do this using `simpleframework xml serialiser`? I can get the whole XML and parse it manually but I am looking for ways to do this via the `simpleframework` API.

Comment: You might consider having a look at this library. https://github.com/stanfy/gson-xml

Comment: I don't want to use any library. I know it is possible to do this via simpleframwork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. simple framework provides utility functions which convert the XML document into Java object list.

More details here http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#util